# Implementation of triggers in cassandra3.0

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, database-trigger

Can someone please explain how to implement the trigger in cassandra. Here What I need is, I have two tables Alarm and AlarmReplica where when data gets updated in Alarm table I need to copy all the data in Alarm to AlarmReplica. So I choosed triggers to implement this work. But unfortunately I don't find any documentation related to cassandra trigger implementation. Since im new to cassandra, can someone help me to implement triggers in cassandra. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what I *think* you may be looking for that may do the work is a materialized view (MVIEW). If data is changed in the base table, the MVIEW is changed as well (it doesn't re-copy the entire table, which you above question seems to say, but it does replicate the changes made from the base table to the MVIEW). If that's what you're referring to, MVIEWS are very easy to use and work fairly well, but as they are replicated components, they can have consistency issues like any other structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find any documentation on triggers because they are deprecated and generally considered a bad idea.

If you really want to use a trigger for this then you could look at the trigger example in the cassandra source code [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cassandra-3.0/examples/triggers).

I'm not 100% clear about your use case here but if you want to write to both tables why not just get the client to do it.

Alternatively, maybe what you need is a second backup datacenter and replicate the alarm table into this datacenter.